# How do I represent a multi-valued attribute in an alfresco aspect property?

Tags: alfresco

I wish to extend the person object with additional attributes through an aspect, however several of the aspect properties need to be multi-valued i.e. contain more than one value.
e.g a person's skill set.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try adding `multiple="true"` to the definition as described [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fmetadata-model-props.html)? If that doesn't work, could you explain some more about what you need and why the normal way fails for you?

Comment: I discovered this shortly after I asked the question. New to alf development and I need to extend a person with additional attributes and also change the form dialog for creating a new person. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is define your property with `multiple="true"` to make it multi-valued. This is detailed [in the documentation here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fmetadata-model-props.html).

If you're new to creating Alfesco models, you might find [these](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Step-By-Step%3a_Creating_A_Custom_Model) [two](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Step_by_Step_Model_Definition) wiki pages helpful. The book Professional Alfresco is also recommended, and the modelling section hasn't changed since it was written (though a few other areas have)

Comment: I actually wanted to extend the Person model and found this: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555 However I can't get it to work since I cant find the SlingshotUserFactory class to extend it in the expanded war files (share &alfresco). Also a reply with an attempt by someone on 4.1 couldn't get it to work so I doubt I can get it to work in 4.2.

Comment: It's still there! [Source code is here](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/source/java/org/alfresco/web/site/SlingshotUserFactory.java) - it should be in the `alfresco-share` jar file in the Share webapp